# Typo3: How to insert data into database in a hook with powermail

Tags: php, typo3

I need to insert data into a column in the database.

Which hook should I use?

How can I insert the data?

I'm very confused over how powermail works with hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, You could use this hook : `PM_SubmitBeforeMarkerHook`, it contains `$sessionData`, with submitted data.

ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['powermail']['PM_SubmitBeforeMarkerHook'][$_EXTKEY] = 'EXT:'.$_EXTKEY.'/Ressources/Private/PHP/Hooks/powermail/class.user_PM_SubmitBeforeMarkerHook.php:&user_PM_SubmitBeforeMarkerHook';
```

class.user_PM_SubmitBeforeMarkerHook.php

```
<?php

class user_PM_SubmitBeforeMarkerHook {
    public function PM_SubmitBeforeMarkerHook (tx_powermail_submit &$pObj, &$markerArray, &$sessionData) {
         // Save data
    }
}
```

Comment: I thing I got it. I had to use sessionData instead. Thanks

Comment: exactly, will adjust the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just as addition: Powermail is able to create or edit tables in the database on its own. You can f.e. create tt_news records via powermail just by define the mapping via TypoScript. Have a closer look into the manual for that.

Comment: Such approach I would recommend only to TYPO3 integrators, who master TypoScript and has no to much great experience in PHP. As a PHP developer I prefer dB inserts with PHP. It gives more possibilities to transform the data and manage exceptions.