# Send information til CampaignMonitor before PowerMail submit

Tags: php, typo3, campaign-monitor

I am trying to send information to CampaignMonitor when af user fill out a form in PowerMail.

I thought that I could use the same example as here: [Typo3: How to insert data into database in a hook with powermail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989803/typo3-how-to-insert-data-into-database-in-a-hook-with-powermail)

Put no matter what I put into the function in class.user_PM_SubmitBeforeMarkerHook.php I get no result. Not even if I just let TYPO3 write in af txt-file.

Doesn't the example work with TYPO3 6.2.3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the example does'nt work in TYPO3 6.2, as it requires Powermail V1

For TYPO3 6.2, you use Powermail v2, which does not use the old hook-concept but signalSlots to enable the possibility to extend Powermail.

I would recommend to read some [documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/femanager/1.0.10/ExtfeManager/BestPractice/UsingSignalslots%28hookPendant%29ToExtendFemanager/Index.html) about signalSlots and then use the [available signalSlots](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/Powermail/ForDevelopers/SignalSlots/Index.html) in Powermail (e.g. AfterMailDbSaved).